# How to create instance of a model with a relationship and nest relationship object in response (FastAPI + SQLAlchemy + Pydantic + Async)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, pydantic

I am having the following issue when displaying/returning and object (after inserting into the DB). The object has a relationship with another object (FK). And I would like the other object be nested in the response JSON of my endpoint.

Error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)`

I understand/think that this is caused by not eager loading the related object, hence the ORM is not able to give it back to the response. How can I eager load the related objects after inserting without explicitly coding and executing another query? (I know the query should execute, but I think I shouldn't be the one to write it)

I am using

```
fastapi==0.75.0
pydantic==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.32
```

And I have the following models:

```py
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    products = relationship("Product", backref="category")


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    quantity = Column(Integer)
    description = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Float)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

and the following pydantic classes:

```py
class Category(BaseModel):
    name: constr(min_length=2, max_length=50)


class CategoryDisplay(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class ProductBase(BaseModel):
    id: int | None
    name: str
    quantity: int
    description: str
    price: float

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class Product(ProductBase):
    category_id: int


class ProductDisplay(ProductBase):
    category: CategoryDisplay

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I am using the async feature for sqlalchemy like the following:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = \
    f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DATABASE_USERNAME}:{DATABASE_PASSWORD}@{DATABASE_HOST}:{DATABASE_PORT}/{DATABASE_NAME}"

engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=DB_ECHO, pool_size=int(DATABASE_POOL_SIZE))

async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

Base = BaseModel

async def get_db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        except SQLAlchemyError as sql_ex:
            await session.rollback()
            raise sql_ex
        except HTTPException as http_ex:
            await session.rollback()
            raise http_ex
        finally:
            await session.close()
```

Now, that `BaseModel` on the models is:

```py
@as_declarative()
class Base:
   id: Any
   async def save(self, db_session: AsyncSession):
       """
       :param db_session:
       :return:
       """
       try:
           db_session.add(self)
           return await db_session.commit()
       except SQLAlchemyError as ex:
           raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail=repr(ex))
```

And I have the following code:

```py
@router.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=schema.ProductDisplay)
async def create_product(
        product: schema.Product,
        database: AsyncSession = Depends(db.get_db),
):
    ret = await create_new_product(product, database)
    return schema.ProductDisplay.from_orm(ret)

async def create_new_product(request: schema.Product, database: AsyncSession) -> models.Product:
    new_product = models.Product(**request.dict())
    await new_product.save(database)
    return new_product
```

again, the error I get when calling that endpoint is:
Error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)`

The object was inserted but it was unable to provide a response.

I hope I've provided enough information and it is clear. Please, let me know if you need any more info to be able to assist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/gordthompson/fastapi-tutorial-postgresql). It implements the FastAPI tutorial with `postgresql+asyncpg` and manages a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Item`.

Comment: @GordThompson, I saw your example. But your `Item` pydantic model, references `owner_id` as an `int`, and in my case I would need to be the nested object, hence referencing a `User` pydantic class (that does not show the `items.

Comment: `owner_id` is the foreign key column in the table. The `owner` attribute (created by the `relationship`) acts as a getter/setter for the related `Owner` object.

Comment: I understand. Notice that in the `ProductDisplay` which I use as `response_model` schema I have `category: CategoryDisplay` which will render the `CategoryDisplay` schema within the `ProductDisplay` schema. Does that make sense? I don't want the `id`, I want the whole object.

Comment: Are you able to resolve it, I am also get this problem pls write solution if solved